# Can't install APK on device

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to install my app on my phone but I got this error :

```
07/28 14:10:53: Launching 'app' on HUAWEI COL-L29.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.

List of apks:
[0] '/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: '-26'
Retry
```

The only way I find to fix it is to uninstall manually my app. Is there another way to manage this ?

Comment: uninstall apk on your device, clean the project and build project again

Comment: May be you have signed apk version of same app installed. If yes., then uninstall that

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I tried to install 2 different version of the same app one after the other to make some test. So I guess there is no other option than remove the apk from the device. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so from your answers the only way to do it is to uninstall the apk on the device.

You can do it manually by longpressing the icon on your phone.

Or with adb `adb uninstall <your_package>`